# Can you turn off all steam leaks or are some impossible?

Tags: lethal-company

Often when exploring a building you will encounter steam leaks, which hamper your vision significantly.  From what I understand, there are "switches" as the game calls them (red circular valves) that you can use to stop the steam leaks.  However, I've never found one of these valves *in or around* the steak leak.  I *have* found them randomly in an otherwise clear area no where near a steam leak and the valve says I cannot use it (presumably because there is no leak for it to stop).

Are all steam leaks possible to stop or are some impossible?  Am I just getting unlucky when I can't find one of these switches for inside a steam leak?

Comment: Not definitive, but after 10 hours of playing I've never found one that couldn't be turned off.  Usually the valve seems to be near one of the jets of steam shooting out.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft After playing more, I think you are right.  Sometimes it's just a little harder than others to find the valve.  You can make an answer if you wish